# Role Manager using SPEAK

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5, sitecore-speak-ui

I am trying to develop a role manager app in SPEAK where users can view the list of available roles and add/modify roles. 
I know that we can get the list of current roles by using the API like this ,
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesManager.GetUsersInRole(Role.FromName("Content Authors"), true);

How do I achieve this in SPEAK ? As there is no controller where I get the model properties and return it to view, how do I get to bind this list to the list page in SPEAK ? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at my following example SPEAK examples.

Here is a SPEAK list control with custom data binding. You can use this to display your data in the list you mention.
http://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/03/30/sitecore-speak-list-component-custom-tile-and-knockout-databinding/

As for exposing the data you require, EntityService allows you to implement custom code and expose any data you wish from your custom controller. There is a JavaScript API allowing you to access the JSON data directly in your SPEAK PageCode.
http://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/01/06/entityservice-sitecore-service-client/

**I have also created some videos on this subject.**

SPEAK List Control and Databinding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKld8i7qX1A
Entity Service: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0cVr6CnNKM